# MFC MessageBox Not Showing at Top Of All Windows

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, message

i have created an Application in VC++, the Problem is that if an Error Occurs i display the MessageBox. but that MessageBox doesn't show at front.  i have to press ALT key to become in-front of that application. My Application becomes in-active until i press ALT. and Press OK on the MessageBox.

Here is the Code Attached.

```
MessageBox(NULL,"Invalid File, Parsing is going to be terminate");
```

`AfxMessageBox("Win32 MessageMessage",MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_TOPMOST);`

i wil very grateful if somebody helps me

Comment: Which one are you using? `MessageBox` or `AfxMessageBox`? And if you're using both...well, *why* are you using both?

Comment: Are you calling this from a different thread? You must pass the handle of the parent window if using the Win32 API version.

Comment: Code Gray: i have used both and they both behaving like same, i have parent Activity inherited from Dialog Class and and i m using a OpenGL window in it.. i m getting the rite way how to use Windows Handler. if i put ::getWindows() as first parameter it wont compile. kindly help me

Comment: In the main dialogue, in the properties of it what are the values of Style and Border? The probelm may be there.

Comment: Post actual repro code (like a complete class/function definition that evinces the behavior you describe), not just the two function calls that you tried at various times. It's pointless to speculate about all of the possible reasons this might not work. It's obviously a focus issue, so you're either doing something in the preceding lines to squirrel away the focus, or you're failing to pass in a valid window handle to the `MessageBox` function call, etc... Also, after you update your question, be sure to use the `@user` notation in your comments if you want to notify people.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass Handle to display Messagebox on Screen,
You can use HWND WINAPI GetDesktopWindow(void); function to get the Handle of Desktop and pass this in MessageBox () function.

You can get more help from

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633504%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

GetDesktopWindoe retrieves a handle to the desktop window. The desktop window covers the entire screen. The desktop window is the area on top of which other windows are painted. So this will work for OpenGL as well.

Comment: I have done by that way. now when i press button from any specific Dialog Window it shows at upfront. Thanks for th ereply

Comment: No, sorry, that's wrong. See [What's so special about the desktop window?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040224-00/?p=40493)