# Why is my AfxMessageBox invisible/hidden until Alt is pressed?

Tags: mfc, visual-studio-2019

I'm working on an MFC app. I have a class inheriting from `CWinApp` which tries to open an `AfxMessageBox` inside its `InitInstance` function.

When the `AfxMessageBox` function is called, no message-box is visible, but I hear a Windows bell sound. If I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>, the message box appears. **Why isn't the `AfxMessageBox` appearing immediately?**

This question mentions a similar issue, but the answer only refers to the non-MFC function `MessageBox`, not `AfxMessageBox` which is what I'm using:

[MFC MessageBox Not Showing at Top Of All Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8848441/mfc-messagebox-not-showing-at-top-of-all-windows)

---

### Update 1

I'm working on a minimal reproducible example, but it's tricky because this is part of a large application with poor encapsulation.

In my app, it appears that a call to the function `ProcessShellCommand()` is causing `AfxMessageBox` to stop working. However, calls to `AfxMessageBox` work correctly both before and after `ProcessShellCommand` in a newly-created MFC application.

It looks like some consequence of calling `ProcessShellCommand` is causing `AfxMessageBox` to behave differently, but I'm not sure how to identify all the consequences of calling `ProcessShellCommand`. When I'm debugging, the particular call to ProcessShellCommand includes a filename, so the file-open command is causing the app's `CView` to be launched.

In the `OnInitialUpdate` code for my `CView`-inheriting class, `AfxMessageBox` functions correctly. The best transition point I can identify between `AfxMessageBox` working, and not working, is when the `CView`'s `OnInitialUpdate` function returns from it being called by `ProcessShellCommand`.

---

### Update 2

It seems that `m_pMainWnd` is `NULL` before the call to `ProcessShellCommand` (while `AfxMessageBox` is working as expected), and non-`NULL` after the call to `ProcessShellCommand`.

Based on this discussion:
[Why would a message box be not displaying?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41106365/why-would-a-message-box-be-not-displaying)
, I tried printing out the message-queue contents before and after the call to `ProcessShellCommand`. Before, the message-queue only contains a single message. Afterwards, the message-queue printout loop is full of `WM_PAINT` and it never terminates until I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>. This makes me think that I'm running into a message-pump-related issue rather than something related to e.g. visibility state.

---------- More observations ------------

It looks like the call to AfxMessageBox stops inside win32u.dll; I determined this by hitting the 'pause execution' button while waiting for the message-box to appear. Here's the call-stack and debug screenshot:

[image: Call stack]
[image: Program pointer]

Comment: A [mcve] is required.

Comment: What version of VS? See also [AfxMessageBox going on background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38457967/afxmessagebox-going-on-background).

Comment: @dxiv VS2019. Thanks, I checked that link - seems to be suggesting a workaround by programmatically creating a key-press via PostMessage(WM_SYSKEYDOWN).  This might be an OK band-aid but I would prefer to solve this the 'right' way.

Comment: @afarley [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41106365/why-would-a-message-box-be-not-displaying) was reported as a bug back then, but the *Microsoft Connect* site was retired since and the old links no longer work.

Comment: In which class are you trying to display it? Your app class or some other? I ask because you can’t use it in your app class I don’t think.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/112788/afxmessagebox-does-not-show-until-34alt34-key-is-p.html

Comment: @AndrewTruckle I'm trying to call it from the InitInstance of my CWinApp class. It works fine until a call to ProcessShellCommand. Why don't you think it can be used in my app? Shouldn't AfxMessageBox be usable from basically anywhere in MFC? I saw that link, but they don't seem to have an answer either.

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/articles/35209/messagebox-in-exitinstance You should add that info.

Comment: It is odd. I recall having an issue in the past with it but now when I check my InitInstance I am using that method with no special code.

Comment: Probably either this form, or one of its child forms or dialogs, is doing something to generate excess WM_PAINT (see the details I just added). I guess the next step is identifying the reason for these messages in the queue.

Comment: [AfxMessageBox](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cstring-formatting-and-message-box-display#afxmessagebox) is essentially a wrapper around [MessageBox](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-messagebox). The latter accepts an explicit owner window handle. The former doesn't, and the owner is deduced from application state. Such is MFC: It seemingly simplifies the interface at the expense of requiring the user to know virtually every aspect of its internal implementation. Start by single-stepping into `AfxMessageBox` and take it from there.

Comment: It's funny that you would see a queue full of WM_PAINT messages, those ordinarily aren't queued but are generated on demand when the queue is empty.  One reason for not seeing a messagebox could be if it were positioned off screen somewhere.

Comment: Auto-generated message pile-up is usually a result of `PeekMeeage`-ing with a message range filter that goes unserved. [Why is my message queue full of WM_TIMER messages?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20160624-00/?p=93745) tells a similar story.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that my `CWinApp` had a `CFrameWnd` class that I had forgotten about; I was focusing too much on the `CView` class.

In the `CFrameWnd` class, in the `BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP` block, there was an `ON_WM_TIMER()`. I removed this from the message-map to test, and the AfxMessageBox() worked as expected.

When I create a fresh SDI application, there is no `ON_WM_PAINT()` in the message-map block, so I think this may have been added incorrectly. The class itself does not implement `OnPaint()`, so I guess this caused some unhandled `WM_PAINT` messages to be floating around.

It's a bit surprising that this doesn't lead to a compiler error; as I understand it, having `ON_WM_PAINT()` only makes sense if there's a corresponding `OnPaint()` function.

Comment: It could be that the base class provides a default `OnPaint` function that doesn't do what you need.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with VS2109. An image is displayed using the OnDraw(..)
function of the Cview class. The user selects a menu command to enter some
data and if the data are not correct the AfxMessageBox(...) is called. Nothing
really out of the ordinary. (I also noticed that when the message window does occasionally appear, it is painted very slowly).

This is a fix I found and I hope it helps. In your application, add the function DoMessageBox(...) with the following statements:

```
int CYourApplicationApp::DoMessageBox(LPCTSTR lpszPrompt, UINT nType, UINT 
nIDPrompt)
{  
    // call the base class
    int res = CWinApp::DoMessageBox(lpszPrompt, nType, nIDPrompt);

    CWnd* pWnd = CWnd::GetActiveWindow();

    ASSERT(pWnd);

    pWnd->PostMessageW(WM_SYSKEYDOWN);

    return res;
}
```

It may also be of general interest to know that one may also get the same problem by simply calling a dialog with the DoModal() function. On occasions, the dialog will appear only after one presses the [alt] key!  It seems to me that there is a general problem with the way the CView class interacts with the CWndFrame class in that (for some unknown reason) it is pumping the latter with WM_PAINT messages.